# How to display returned JSON from a jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to get display return values from the JSON values.I need to get value the user id

```
 $('User_id').observe('blur', function(e) {
   var txt = $('User_id').value;
   jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'get',
     url: BASE_URL + 'admin/index/user_id',
     data: {
       user_id: txt
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
       console.log('success' + data.success);
       if (data.success) {
         var Value = data.location.user_id;
         alert(Value);
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

These values are getting in html form. In that I need to store user id in Value varable. But I receive successundefined as a output..

```
[{
  "user_id": "139",
  "mobile": "9042843911",
  "gender": "male",
  "hashcode": "DfAbMqLApAV6nVa1z940",
  "username": "anandhsp21",
  "password": "74bcff7d1199012e154f364e3f65e31d:8I",
  "authorized_person": "Anandh",
  "created": "2015-06-08 13:46:55",
  "modified": "2015-06-08 06:43:35",
  "logdate": "2015-06-08 08:16:55",
  "lognum": "12",
  "reload_acl_flag": "0",
  "is_active": "1",
  "extra": "N;",
  "rp_token": null,
  "rp_token_created_at": null,
  "app_name": "",
  "api_key": ""
}]
```

Please some one help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: is this json actually what you received as response. because this is array and not an object so it does not have success prop nor location prop?

Comment: Where do you recieve success undefined ??

Comment: Are u saying that u are getting response in json format from ajax call and u need to read ur json response?

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Comment: Yes I just use var userid = data[0].user_id;
It solves my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get the data in array so use loop in success data

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    console.log('success' + data[i].user_id );
}
```

If you know the record length is 1 then use directly

```
 console.log('success' + data[0].user_id );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array that contains one object. So you can access this object using :

```
success: function(data){
    console.log('success' + data[0].user_id );
```

Trying to log `success` is pointless, because there is no `success` key whatsoever in the received data.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you get the response in proper json format,and as harshad pointed String male should be wrapped in double quotes.

After you get that fixed,you can access the user_id as:

```
data[0].user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.success` is undefined, because the received data is stored directly in `data`. That's the first argument of the success block. You can access the received data directly by `data[0]` to get the object inside of the array, or if you have a larger array you can do a for each loop over it, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Try this, simply use json.parse()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var v = ['{"user_id":"139","mobile":"9042843911"}'];
  var obj = JSON.parse(v);
  alert(obj.user_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get userid please follow below code I edited,

```
$('User_id').observe('blur', function(e) {
   var txt = $('User_id').value;
   jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: BASE_URL + 'admin/index/user_id',
   data: {
     user_id: txt
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
     // this below userid is the value user_id you want.
     var userid = data[0].user_id;
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a json error

```
"gender":male
```

Strings **male** should be wrapped in double quotes.

you need to make sure that your response is formatted appropriately and according [JSON.org](http://json.org/) standards.